# Visual Studio 2012 can't resolve namespace even though DLL reference seems fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-mvc-5, sitecore, sitecore-mvc

I have attempted to create an MVC 5 project by creating an MVC 4 project in Visual Studio 2012 and installing MVC 5 through Nuget.
I can build this fine.

I attempt to add a reference to another DLL, Sitecore.Mvc.DLL, which I can see was built against MVC 5.1.0. The DLL reference is added fine, and there seems to be no .NET framework conflict (which is where I've seen this issue in the past).

I'm trying to add a using statement to my code:-

```
using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation;
```

IntelliSense picks this up fine....even allowing me to auto-complete 'Presentation'.

However when I build I get the following error:-

```
The type or namespace name 'Sitecore' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What could be the issue here?

I'm using:-

- Visual Studio 2012 - Update 4
- MVC 4 Web Application (initially)
- MVC 5.1.0 Nuget Package
- Sitecore 7.2 - Update 2 (where Sitecore.Mvc.DLL comes from)
- .NET 4.5.2 installed on my machine.

Comment: `The DLL reference is added fine, and there seems to be no .NET framework conflict (which is where I've seen this issue in the past).` It still looks to me this is a .NET framework versions conflict. It could be that `Sitecore.Mvc.DLL` references **another dll** with conflicting .NET framework version.

Comment: Seems to me that all Sitecore DLLs reference the same .NET Framework. If what you suggest was the case, people wouldn't be able to reference the Sitecore.Mvc.DLL even in VS2013, right? I haven't been able to find any reports of this error before.

Comment: Could you tell which .net framework version your mvc application is built and which .net framework version the Sitecore.Mvc.DLL is built? .NET framework version is different from your MVC version (`MVC 5.1.0`)

Comment: Yeah, that's what (I believe) I was checking. In ILSpy (or Reflector), the DLLs have a reference to mscorelib....and for all of them, this is // mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089

Comment: Nothing wrong with you setup, maybe try and redo everything from scratch

Comment: Do yu have a web.config included in your web app?

Comment: Yep, a clean Sitecore Web.Config is included. Created a blank solution and tried again. Same issue. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I'm using a different version of Sitecore.Mvc.DLL, which IS targeted to .NET 4.5.1. Seems like the mscorelib reference in Reflector doesn't quite tell all the details.

Now I need to target my Web App to .NET 4.5.1, which means I need to follow the steps here to be able to select it.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2013/08/08/building-apps-with-the-net-framework-4-5-1-preview-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx

Thanks, and sorry to @Khanh TO, and everyone else for helping out.